# Timestamp changes when replacing text in a Google Doc Template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-docs

I have a Google Form for customers to enter event details for Catering. App Script then creates a Google Calendar event, opens a Google Doc Template to replace corresponding text, converts the doc to a pdf and emails me a copy of it before deleting it from my Drive.

In the code here the **Calendar Event** is using the "**var timeString**". And the **Rename Text in Document** is using  "**var timeFormat**" in order to not show the seconds and GSM. They both are pulling the data from the "**time = newRequest[0][14]**" cell in the spreadsheet. But for some reason that I can not explain when a time of 10:15, 10:45, 11:15, 11:45, 12:15 and 12:45 are entered the script changes the time on the Doc Template to **:10, **:40. It doesn't happen if the time is a single digit hour. I don't understand why this is happening, please help?

```
//rename data into useable tags  
  timestamp = newRequest[0][0],
  company = newRequest[0][1],
  contact_name = newRequest[0][2],
  contact_email = newRequest[0][3],
  contact_phone = newRequest[0][4],
  onsite_name = newRequest[0][5],
  onsite_phone = newRequest[0][6],
  pickup_delivery = newRequest[0][7],
  day = newRequest[0][8],
  address = newRequest[0][9],
  location = newRequest[0][10],
  parking = newRequest[0][11],
  guests = newRequest[0][12],
  other = newRequest[0][13],
  time = newRequest[0][14];
  date = newRequest[0][15]

//create new calendar event  
  var dateString = date.toDateString();
  var dateFormat = dateString.substr(4,11);
  var timeString = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes();
  var timeFormat = time.toLocaleTimeString().substr(0,4) + time.toLocaleTimeString().substr(7,4);
  var endtimeString = (time.getHours() + 1) + ":" + time.getMinutes();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('haleyhouse.org_1oicreouarl3je785ltupuoppg@group.calendar.google.com');
  var event = calendar.createEvent(contact_name + ", " + company + ", " + contact_phone, 
      new Date(dateString + " " + timeString), 
      new Date(dateString + " " + endtimeString), 
      {description: timestamp + " received form request - google", location: address});

//rename text in the document
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDay', day);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', dateFormat)
  copyBody.replaceText('keyTime', timeFormat)
  copyBody.replaceText('keyCompany', company);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyContact_Name', contact_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyContact_Email', contact_email);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyContact_Phone',contact_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOnsite_Name', onsite_name);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyOnsite_Phone', onsite_phone);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDelivery', pickup_delivery);  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyAddress', address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyLocation', location);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyGuests', guests);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apps script the Utilities.formatDate() is your friend.

Try this:

```
  var startDate = dateString+' '+time;
  var timeFormat = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(startDate), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'hh:mm');
  Logger.log(timeFormat)
```

Make sure the script project properties is set to the correct timezone.

Comment: Thank you! Utilities.formatDate() IS my friend. That just made everything work smoother. And it got rid of my weird "**:15" bug.